# proxy_pass configuration in NGINX

Tags: nginx, python-sphinx, nginx-location, proxypass

I'm trying to figure out how to pass an external request via `proxy_pass` in NGINX. In particular I want to load [Sphinx Documentation source](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) from http://example.com/documentation/, but actually after restarting NGINX server I got 502 Bad Gateway, probably derived by a not proper configuration.

Here's my example configuration:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www;

    location /documentation {

        proxy_pass http://example.com:8000;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

}
```

In my opinion it should work, any suggestions?

Consider that if I try to launch the Sphinx source via ssh console without NGINX configuration, it works but the source path is like this: http://example.com:8000, not the best way to display it.

Also because I need to load it every times via the console command:

> sphinx-autobuild source build/html --host http://example.com --port8000

I didn't find nothing about launch it in a specific subfolder of the host, for example the subfolder /documentation.

**[Update]**

I have tried to replace `example.com` with `localhost` instruction as suggested by @Johnny Logan, and I got a **502 Bad Request** with this strange kind of result request in the address bar:

```
http://example.com/documentation:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000/
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're connecting to example.com again -- I suppose you want to get to port 8000 internally? You may want to substitute 'localhost' in the configuration:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www;

    location /documentation {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

}
```

This way you also don't need to have port 8000 open -- everything goes through port 80 or 443.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have already tried with localhost but it still not working. That's the reason I have set example.com as proxy_pass instruction. Have you take a look to the ssh command that I use for launch the sphinx documentation? This is why I use port 8000, in that case it works but I want to configure it automatically via NGINX in order to automatize the process and set the location in a specific subfolder.

Comment: Having not used this, but a shot in the dark: Change the commend to launch sphinx as well to use localhost as host? Something like "sphinx-autobuild source build/html --host localhost --port8000" or "sphinx-autobuild source build/html --host 127.0.0.1 --port8000"

Comment: The ssh instruction works fine, and it's this one:                                          sphinx-autobuild -B source build/html -H example.com -p8000
 but my problem is that the view result is http://example.com:8000 and not http://example.com/documentation:8000. Also the main problem is that I always have to use this ssh command for make the source get online. I need something that can handle automatically this command request.